# Search a boost MPL sequence for a type with a boost placeholder

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I have a boost mpl vector with different types and want to know if one specific type is in that vector. But that type contains a template parameter that is a boost placeholder (which I want to replace afterwards)
Code:

```
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE 20
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_MAP_SIZE 20
#include <boost/typeof/std/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>

namespace bmpl = boost::mpl;

template< class In, class Out = bmpl::_1 >
struct BSI{
    typedef typename Out::FrameType FrameType;
};

int main(){
    typedef BSI<float> foot;
    typedef bmpl::vector< int, foot > vec;
    typename bmpl::find_if< vec, bmpl::same_as<foot> >::type x;
}
```

Problem is: Boost seems to get confused by the placeholder and tries to apply my placeholder. Of course I can write an own placeholder and applier, but is this possible with boost itself?

Comment: If you mean you're using implementation details of Boost MPL for your own meta-programming library semantics, you got what you deserved :/ It could be that Boost MPL allows you to "quote" the place-holder, but I wouldn't count on it (given the age and supported platforms for MPL)

Comment: I want to use boost::apply on foot afterwards. And this is what the boost placeholders are for, aren't they?

Comment: Except you now also want to treat them as non-magical entities. It's either the one or the other. You can probably use your own trivial quoter: `template<typename T> struct quoted { typedef T type; };` and unpack when you are going to "apply on foot" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note that Boost placeholders are not an "implementation" detail of Boost MPL but actually designed for use: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/apply.html

However the behaviour observed here seems to be expected: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/placeholders.html There they have an example:

```
mpl::multiplies<
    mpl::plus<_1,_2>,
    mpl::minus<_1,_2>
>
```

So Solution seems to be to wrap the class in question in a quoter (as mentioned in the comments) like:

```
template<class T>
struct Quote{
    using type = T;
}
```

I'm still not sure if there is a prefered solution within the boost MPL like the protect or quote templates although I did not found appropriate examples for use of them.